# Write in an ellipsis and master its shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, ellipse

thanks to the help of someone on this forum, I can finally write on two different levels in my ellipses. However, I now have another problem with the shape of the ellipses. The top level of my ellipse always contains a single word, but on the bottom level I sometimes have to write more words one under the other, and the more words there are, the more the ellipse takes on the shape of an egg. Is there any way of making Latex understand that ellipses must always be elongated horizontally?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={216mm,330mm},tmargin=20mm,bmargin=20mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,fit}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\tikzset{
    basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        text width=0.3\textwidth,
        align=center,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Ellipse/.style={
        ellipse, 
        draw, 
        shape aspect=2, 
        inner sep=5pt,
        text centered,
        fill=blue!10!white,
        font=\itshape
    },
    splitEllipse/.style={
        draw, 
        fill=blue!10!white,
        shape=ellipse split,
        align=center,
        minimum width=1cm,
        inner sep=5pt,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
\node[Ellipse,](Association 1){Association 1};
 \node[splitEllipse, below= 0.5cm and 0.5cm of Association 1](Relation 7){Relation 7\\
        \nodepart{lower}
        A71 \\
        A72\\
        A73};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\node[splitEllipse, below= 0.5cm of Association 1, minimum width=8cm]` do what you want?

Comment: With "width" I find the ellipse huge compared to what's inside, but it's probably my only option I suppose?